# Ecto - Inserting both sides of a foreign key constraint using cast_assoc and transactions

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a very large set of interlinked records I'm trying to save all at once using cast_assoc, but one of the records has a foreign key constraint to another part of the record set.

```
  @primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
  schema "c_rtu" do
    field(:name, :string)
    has_many(:communication_maps, CommunicationMap)
    has_many(:rtu_streams, RtuStream)

    timestamps()
  end

 @primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
  schema "c_rtu_stream" do
    field(:type, :string)
    field(:type_position, :integer)
    belongs_to(:template, Template, foreign_key: :template_id)
    has_many(:collection_methods, CollectionMethod)
    belongs_to(
      :c_station_channel,
      StationChannel,
      foreign_key: :station_channel_id,
      on_replace: :update
    )
    belongs_to(:c_rtu, Rtu, foreign_key: :rtu_id, on_replace: :update)
    timestamps()
  end

@primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
  schema "c_collection_method" do
    field(:method, :string)
    belongs_to(:c_rtu_stream, RtuStream, foreign_key: :rtu_stream_id, on_replace: :update)
    belongs_to(:c_section, Section, foreign_key: :section_id, on_replace: :update)
    has_many(:instances, Instance)

    timestamps()
  end

@primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
  schema "c_instance" do
    field(:calculation_method, :string)
    belongs_to(:c_field, Field, foreign_key: :field_id, on_replace: :update)
    belongs_to(
      :c_collection_method,
      CollectionMethod,
      foreign_key: :collection_method_id,
      on_replace: :update
    )
    timestamps()
  end

@primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
  schema "c_field" do
    field(:name, :string)
    has_many(:instances, Instance)
    belongs_to(
      :c_communication_map,
      CommunicationMap,
      foreign_key: :communication_map_id,
      on_replace: :update
    )
    timestamps()
  end

@primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
  schema "c_communication_map" do
    field(:name, :string)
    field(:type, :string)
    has_many(:fields, Field)
    belongs_to(:c_rtu, Rtu, foreign_key: :rtu_id, on_replace: :update)
    timestamps()
  end
```

I have a one-way foreign key constraint between c_instance -> c_field (c_instance requires c_field exists).

I'm currently trying to insert this using c_rtu as the base, but I'm coming up against the issue where, despite having one branch with c_communication_map and c_field and one with c_rtu_stream, c_collection_method and c_instance, even with the uuids pre-filled it hits the constraint for the c_field not existing.

Is there anyway to handle this kind of circular relationship being inserted by using cast_assoc?

Comment: have you tried using Ecto.Multi?

Comment: I have tried using Ecto.Multi and using a transaction, but it suffers the same issue that the required records aren't in the database when it's validating the constraint. The current implementation is two chained Ecto.Multi tranactions (inserting a->c, then d<-a), checking that the first chain was successful before inserting the latter.

Comment: please read the documentation of Ecto.Multi carefully, you can get the intermediary results before committing the transaction, here is a example: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html#insert_all/5-example

Comment: I clearly I don't understand something. The issue I have isn't that I need to check before committing the transaction, it's that they need to be inserted into the database before checking. Doing them in the same transaction causes them to be flagged at invalid, despite that the records are about to be inserted earlier in the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste your code please here!!
And please double check **Schema "d"**, I think it should be

```
schema "d" do
   belongs_to :c, C
   belongs_to :e, E
end
```

Thanks!!

Comment: It should be, that's an error on my typing it up. I'll paste my code in.